# Qual è il senso di "si vede" in questo passaggio?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Vita i medici non li può vedere. I medici del Bellevue hanno portato via Lena su una barella. Delirava. L’hanno coperta con un lenzuolo. È rimasta fuori solo una mano. Se lo meritava, che aveva il diavolo in corpo, e ha fatto dimenticare Dionisia a Agnello e Vita a Diamante. Però le sue urla hanno svegliato tutta la casa e le fiamme blu hanno distrutto il materasso, i sacchi di farina e la tenda a fiori. Sono morte anche le galline. I medici sono spariti al terzo piano. Quando sono tornati giú, Vita ne ha preso uno per la manica. **Si vede**? gli ha chiesto. **Si vede** sí, ha risposto sgarbatamente il medico, sono ustioni di secondo grado.

Non capisco il significato di questo "si vede" che appare in questo testo. Ho cercato il verbo "vedere" in alcuni dizionari, ma ci sono tante accezioni che non riesco a capacitarmi a quale possa corrispondere l'uso che se ne fa nel brano sopra citato. Potreste aiutarmi a chiarire il mio dubbio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semplicemente Vita chiedeva se si vedesse l’ustione che aveva Lena sul corpo.

Implicitamente il *si vede* si riferisce appunto all’ustione e altrettanto implicitamente ha risposto il medico.

Comment: Scusa, @abarisone, ma chi ha ustioni sul corpo? Vita?

Comment: @Charo L’ustione effettivamente l’aveva Lena. Ho specificato meglio la risposta

Comment: Se è così, non avevo proprio capito nulla.

Answer (score 2):

Per completare la buona risposta di @abarisone, aggiungo che il verbo impersonale "vedersi" (uso impersonale del verbo "vedere" più la particella impersonale "si") ha come accezione primaria "essere visibile".

Esempi:

*Si vede la torre di Pisa dalla tua finestra? No. Ci sono dei palazzi davanti.*

*La nebbia era così fitta che non si vedeva nulla.*

*Questa galleria è così lunga che non si vede ancora l'uscita.*

*Venere è un pianeta così luminoso che talvolta si vede ad occhio nudo anche di giorno.*

*Luca si è scottato al sole così tanto che la pelle arrossata si vede ad un chilometro di distanza!* (iperbole)

*Bello quell'orologio! Le lancette sono fosforescenti e si vedono anche al buio!*

*Questo lavoro è così lungo che non se ne vede la fine!* (figurato)